# Custom EditForm.aspx with Visual Studio showing columns as usual

Tags: sharepoint

I need to create a custom EditForm.aspx for a list (the list can have any fields (including custom SPFields). I MUST use Visual Studio (and **NOT** SharePoint Designer).

Q 1) Will Application Page be a right option?

Q 2) I can get the list and its fields via `List.Fields` collection. But I cannot figure out how to add these fields to a panel in application page? Following code does NOT work, but can probably clarify what I want.

```
foreach (SPField fld in list.Fields)
{
  this.pPanel.Controls(fld);
}
```

SharePoint's default EditForm.aspx does what I need actually. Whatever fields we set as columns (spfields) appear automatically in EditForm, DisplayForm and NewForm pages. I must create the same functionality on a custom page.

Answer (score 1):

Like the out of the box EditForm.aspx, add a [ListFormWebPart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.listformwebpart.aspx) to your page.

```
<Module Name="CustomEdit" Url="">
    <File Url="CustomEditForm.aspx" Type="Ghostable">
      <AllUsersWebPart WebPartZoneID="Main" WebPartOrder="1">
        <![CDATA[
          <WebPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
            <Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>
            <TypeName>Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ListFormWebPart</TypeName>
            <PageType>PAGE_EDITFORM</PageType>
          </WebPart>]]>
      </AllUsersWebPart>
    </File>
</Module>
```